# F# NUnit test comes back as not being run

Tags: f#, nunit, assert

I am working with `VS 2013`, `F#` and `NUnit`. It is worth noting I am novice with `F#`.

I have added very basic test and when I attach debugger to `NUnit` and run it in debug mode breakpoint is being hit however test comes back as not being run.
`NUnit` identifies it as test but does not run(assumption) `Assert` (can be seen in bottom screenshot).

[image]

[image]

Test:

```
module Test
open NUnit.Framework

[<TestFixture>]
type Test() = 
    [<Test>]
    let ConcatinationTest =
       Assert.AreEqual(Implementation.Concat("aaa"), "rootaaa")
       |> ignore
```

Implementation:

```
module Implementation

let Concat(text:string) = 
    "root"+ text
```

**My expectations must be wrong. Why doesn't it work?**

Comment: You defined it as a value, but it must be a method: `static member ConcatinationTest () = ...`

Comment: @bytebuster Hi, it did it. Could you post it as an answer please. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined it as a value, but it must be a method:

```
[<Test>]
static member ConcatinationTest () = ...
```

<sub>(converted a comment into an answer, as per OP's request)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

OP here, for those who are wondering this works.

```
module Test
open NUnit.Framework

[<TestFixture>]
type Test() = 
    member this.ConcatinationTestData() = 
        [new TestCaseData("roottext","text"); new TestCaseData("root","")]
    [<Test>]
    [<TestCaseSource("ConcatinationTestData")>]
    static member ConcatinationTest(expected:string, text:string) =
       Assert.AreEqual(expected,Implementation.Concat(text))
       |> ignore
```

Debug -> Attach to process -> nunit-agent.exe

Result:
[image]